# HTML Web Form and File Upload to Google Drive and Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a web form made from google app script that accept data and add the data in google sheet. I also want to add a file upload input but it breaks when I add the that, only only input gene_by coming in the sheet. I also want to add code that will save the attached file on google drive and its link in google sheet.

[app script](https://script.google.com/d/1KPJa2UhU0y6kfNEscX87bcmoNZK_GBkwk2xOZSItrUXRwqA2ortz1yFQ/edit?usp=sharing)

[google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eqq5nVtPZIZP1zun0i6XFsGUDquDxaelWhqPUF_oGS4/edit?usp=sharing)

code.gs

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
  
}

function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function processForm(formObject){
  var url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eqq5nVtPZIZP1zun0i6XFsGUDquDxaelWhqPUF_oGS4/edit";
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT+0530","dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

  ws.appendRow([
    formObject.expa_number,
    timestamp,
    formObject.gene_by,
    formObject.company_name,
    formObject.bill_number,
    formObject.bill_date,
    formObject.party_name,
    formObject.description,
    formObject.ledger1,
    formObject.amount1,
    formObject.ledger2,
    formObject.amount2,
    formObject.ledger3,
    formObject.amount3,
    formObject.ledger4,
    formObject.amount4,
    formObject.gst_app,
    formObject.tds_app,
    formObject.tds_rate,
    formObject.payment_status,
    formObject.paid_by,
    formObject.payment_mode,
    formObject.total_amount,
    formObject.attach_bill
  ]);
}

function getEmployee() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1uuOUGssKRCEq8YG7P1R0V33-d6C6p6BoVXa-COckqLo');
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Employee Database')
    var list  = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
    
    return list
}

function getParty() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ntaSlBcWpSJ35ygGpKxUk3QZ-Ipd3CilKtr3_GXlp7w');
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Ledger Names')
    var list  = sheet.getRange(2, 7, sheet.getRange('G2:G').getValues().filter(String).length, 1).getValues();

    return list
}

function getCompany() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ntaSlBcWpSJ35ygGpKxUk3QZ-Ipd3CilKtr3_GXlp7w');
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(`Company's Bank Details`)
    var list  = sheet.getRange(2, 8, sheet.getRange('H2:H').getValues().filter(String).length, 1).getValues();
    
    return list
}

function getExpenseLedger() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ntaSlBcWpSJ35ygGpKxUk3QZ-Ipd3CilKtr3_GXlp7w');
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(`Expense Ledgers | Headings`)
    var list  = sheet.getRange(2, 9, sheet.getRange('I2:I').getValues().filter(String).length, 1).getValues();
    
    return list
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <!-- Select2 CSS --> 
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 

<!-- jQuery --> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<!-- Select2 JS --> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
<?!= include('CSS'); ?>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
<p class="h4 mb-4 text-center">EXPENSES VOUCHER FORM</p>

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label for="company_name">Company Name</label>
      <select type="search" class="form-control" name="company_name" id="company_name" required>
        <option value="" selected hidden> -- select an option -- </option>
        <option></option>
        </select>
  </div>
</div> <!--O1-->

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="expa_number">EXPA Number?</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="expa_number" name="expa_number" placeholder="EXPA#" readonly required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="expa_date">EXPA Date?</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="expa_date" name="expa_date" placeholder="EXPA Date" readonly required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="gene_by">Generated By?</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="gene_by" id="gene_by" required>
        <option>Dipali Chauhan</option>
        </select>
  </div>
  </div> <!--O2-->

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label style="font-size: 14px" for="payment_status">Payment Status? (Select Paid Only if Paid by employee)</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="payment_status" id="payment_status" required>
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
        <option value="Paid">Paid</option>
        <option value="Not_Paid">Not Paid</option>
        </select>
      </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="paid_by">Paid By?</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="paid_by" id="paid_by" required>
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="payment_mode">Mode of Payment?</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="payment_mode" name="payment_mode" placeholder="Mode of Payment" required>
  </div>
</div> <!--O3-->

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label for="description">Description</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Description" required>
  </div>
</div> <!--O4-->

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="party_name">Party Name?</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="party_name" id="party_name" required>
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="bill_number">Bill Number</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bill_number" name="bill_number" placeholder="Bill Number" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="bill_date">Bill Date</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="bill_date" name="bill_date" placeholder="Bill Date" required>
  </div>
</div> <!--O5-->

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="ledger1">Ledger Heading 1</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="ledger1" id="ledger1" required>
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
        </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="amount1">Amount 1</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount1" name="amount1" placeholder="Amount 1" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="ledger2">Ledger Heading 2</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="ledger2" id="ledger2">
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
        </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="amount2">Amount 2</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount2" name="amount2" placeholder="Amount 2">
  </div>
</div> <!--O6-->

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="ledger3">Ledger Heading 3</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="ledger3" id="ledger3">
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
        </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="amount3">Amount 3</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount3" name="amount3" placeholder="Amount 3">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="ledger4">Ledger Heading 4</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="ledger4" id="ledger4">
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
        </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="amount4">Amount 4</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount4" name="amount4" placeholder="Amount 4">
  </div>
</div> <!--O7-->

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="gst_app">GST Applicable?</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="gst_app" id="gst_app" required>
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="tds_app">TDS Applicable?</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="tds_app" id="tds_app" required>
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="tds_rate">TDS Rate (%)?</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="tds_rate" name="tds_rate" placeholder="TDS Rate" min="0.1" max="20" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="total_amount">Total Bill Amount?</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="total_amount" name="total_amount" placeholder="Total Bill Amount" required>
  </div>
</div> <!--O8-->

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label for="attach_bill">Attach Bill?</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="attach_bill" name="attach_bill" placeholder="Attach Bill" readonly required>
  </div>
</div> <!--O9-->
<!-- <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label for="attach_ledger">Attach Ledger?</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" id="attach_ledger" name="attach_ledger" required>
  </div>
</div> 10 -->

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
</div>
</div>      
</div>
<script>
  google.script.url.getLocation(function(location){
    document.getElementById('expa_number').value = location.parameters.expa_number[0];
    document.getElementById('attach_bill').value = location.parameters.attach_bill[0];
  })
</script>
<?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript.html

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
 var arrayCompanyName = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) {
           var companySelect = document.getElementById("company_name");
           ar.forEach(function(pb)
           {
             let option = document.createElement("option");
             option.textContent = pb[0];
             companySelect.appendChild(option);
           })
         }).getCompany();
  var arrayEmployeeName = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) {
           var employeeSelect = document.getElementById("paid_by");
           var employeeSelect2 = document.getElementById("gene_by");
           ar.forEach(function(pb)
           {
             let option = document.createElement("option");
             option.textContent = pb[0];
             employeeSelect.appendChild(option);
           })
           ar.forEach(function(pb1)
           {
             let option = document.createElement("option");
             option.textContent = pb1[0];
             employeeSelect2.appendChild(option);
           })
         }).getEmployee();
  var arrayPartyName = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) {
           var partySelect = document.getElementById("party_name");
           ar.forEach(function(pb)
           {
             let option = document.createElement("option");
             option.textContent = pb[0];
             partySelect.appendChild(option);
           })
         }).getParty();
  var arrayLedgerName = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) {
           var ledgerSelect1 = document.getElementById("ledger1");
           var ledgerSelect2 = document.getElementById("ledger2");
           var ledgerSelect3 = document.getElementById("ledger3");
           var ledgerSelect4 = document.getElementById("ledger4");
           ar.forEach(function(pb1)
           {
             let option = document.createElement("option");
             option.textContent = pb1[0];
             ledgerSelect1.appendChild(option);
           })
           ar.forEach(function(pb2)
           {
             let option = document.createElement("option");
             option.textContent = pb2[0];
             ledgerSelect2.appendChild(option);
           })
           ar.forEach(function(pb3)
           {
             let option = document.createElement("option");
             option.textContent = pb3[0];
             ledgerSelect3.appendChild(option);
           })
           ar.forEach(function(pb4)
           {
             let option = document.createElement("option");
             option.textContent = pb4[0];
             ledgerSelect4.appendChild(option);
           })
         }).getExpenseLedger();
  $("#company_name").select2({
    data: arrayCompanyName
  });
  $("#paid_by").select2({
    data: arrayEmployeeName
  });
  $("#gene_by").select2({
    data: arrayEmployeeName
  });
  $("#party_name").select2({
    data: arrayPartyName
  });
  $("#ledger1").select2({
    data: arrayLedgerName
  });
  $("#ledger2").select2({
    data: arrayLedgerName
  });
  $("#ledger3").select2({
    data: arrayLedgerName
  });
  $("#ledger4").select2({
    data: arrayLedgerName
  });
  
});

  let paymetStaus = document.querySelector("#payment_status");
  let paidBy = document.querySelector("#paid_by");
  let modeOfPayment = document.querySelector("#payment_mode");
  let amount1 = document.querySelector("#amount1");
  let ledger2 = document.querySelector("#ledger2");
  let ledger3 = document.querySelector("#ledger3");
  let ledger4 = document.querySelector("#ledger4");
  let amount2 = document.querySelector("#amount2");
  let amount3 = document.querySelector("#amount3");
  let amount4 = document.querySelector("#amount4");
  let tdsApp = document.querySelector("#tds_app");
  let tdsRate = document.querySelector("#tds_rate");

paidBy.disabled = true;
ledger2.disabled = true;
ledger3.disabled = true;
ledger4.disabled = true;
amount2.disabled = true;
amount3.disabled = true;
amount4.disabled = true;
modeOfPayment.disabled = true;
tds_rate.disabled = true;  

paymetStaus.addEventListener("change", stateHandlePaid_by);
function stateHandlePaid_by() {
    if (paymetStaus.value !== "Paid") {
        paidBy.disabled = true; 
        modeOfPayment.disabled = true; 
        paid_by.value = "";
        modeOfPayment.value = "";
    } else {
        paidBy.disabled = false;
        modeOfPayment.disabled = false; 
    }
}
amount1.addEventListener("change", stateHandleLedger2);
function stateHandleLedger2() {
    if (amount1.value !== "") {
        ledger2.disabled = false;
        amount2.disabled = false; 
    } else {
        ledger2.disabled = true; 
        amount2.disabled = true; 
        ledger2.value = "";
        amount2.value = "";
    }
}
amount2.addEventListener("change", stateHandleLedger3);
function stateHandleLedger3() {
    if (amount2.value !== "") {
        ledger3.disabled = false;
        amount3.disabled = false; 
    } else {
        ledger3.disabled = true; 
        amount3.disabled = true; 
        ledger3.value = "";
        amount3.value = "";
    }
}
amount3.addEventListener("change", stateHandleLedger4);
function stateHandleLedger4() {
    if (amount3.value !== "") {
        ledger4.disabled = false;
        amount4.disabled = false; 
    } else {
        ledger4.disabled = true; 
        amount4.disabled = true; 
        ledger4.value = "";
        amount4.value = "";
    }
}
tds_app.addEventListener("change", stateHandleTdsRate);
function stateHandleTdsRate() {
    if (tds_app.value !== "Yes") {
        tds_rate.disabled = true;
        tds_rate.value = "";
    } else {
        tds_rate.disabled = false; 
    }
}
    
  $('#expa_date').val(new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10));
  
  function preventFormSubmit(){
    var forms=document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i=0;i<forms.length;i++){
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
window.addEventListener('load',preventFormSubmit);

function handleFormSubmit(formObject){
  google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
  $('#myForm').trigger("reset");
$('#myForm').find('select').each(function(){
  $(this).change();
});
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}

</script>
```

CSS.html

```
<style>
.select2-selection__rendered {
    line-height: 38px !important;
}
.select2-container .select2-selection--single {
    height: 38px !important;
}
.select2-selection__arrow {
    height: 38px !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: google.script.run does not return anything directly.  Instead it is returned to the Success Handler.  Try some simple examples before return to your current code.  There are so many things wrong with it I don't know where to begin.